# Placeholders set and param binded-no errors and now all data cannot be displayed

Tags: php

For your info, please don't kill me instantly as I'm asking a question which I have no experience and that is why I'm asking a question.

I have problem below, somewhere around placeholders. the problem is, its  joint table. I have limited knowledge in php. No errors and no data displayed. tq.

```
/calling for record from table-users and table-useradvert, joined
```

...extract below

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){


   $userName = $_POST['username']; $query = "SELECT users.id, users.name, users.username, users.telno, useradvert.id, useradvert.name2, useradvert.color2, useradvert.hobby2, useradvert.radiobtn, useradvert.kupon, useradvert.image, useradvert.image2 ". "FROM users, useradvert ". "WHERE users.id = useradvert.id AND username=?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row = $res->fetch_array();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];
     $_SESSION['name2'] = $row['name2'];
     $_SESSION['color2'] = $row['color2'];
     $_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row['hobby2'];
     $_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row['radiobtn'];
     $_SESSION['kupon'] = $row['kupon'];
     $_SESSION['image'] = $row['image'];
     $_SESSION['image2'] = $row['image2'];
```

extract below same page...

```
</head>



<body>
<div id="apDiv3">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="TabbedPanelsContent">
  <?php
  //display record from table- users (parent table can display)
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
?>

<?php
//display records from table -useradvert (child table cannot display)

while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
"<br/>";
"<br/>";
"<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['color2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['hobby2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['radiobtn']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['kupon']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image2']."<br/>";



}


 ?>
```

Comment: `users.id = useradvert.id` means that `id` or record of `users` table should be the same as `id` in `useradvert` table, then these two records will be joined as one.

Comment: tq kind samaritan @u_mulder. God bless you 1000x times. Yes correct. I have another page which I can insert data both in parent and child table. the two tables are joined perfectly in sql. the only problem is i cannot display data from both table. Previously, i can, but only the parent. after joining them together, it gets worst. please help .tq

Comment: I dont know how to display data when it comes to joint tables. i already search in internet but could not find any solution due to my lack of knowledge which is limited.

Comment: Maybe you need to `execute` query? And do some `foreach` loop on results?

Comment: yes.. done that.. see above.. just cannot display the data now .. no errors prompted.

Comment: i think there is something wrong around SELECT and bindparam..but just not sure..if anyone(that are kind) knows please help..tq

Answer (score 0):

It's ok problem solved. tq btw i appreciate so much for your help.

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){



    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row = $res->fetch_array();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];



    $query = "SELECT useradvert.name2, useradvert.color2, useradvert.hobby2,useradvert.radiobtn, useradvert.kupon, useradvert.image, useradvert.image2 FROM users INNER JOIN useradvert ON users.id=useradvert.id ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row2 = $res->fetch_array();

  // $_SESSION['name'] = $row2['name'];
    $_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
    $_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
    $_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
    $_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
    $_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
    $_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
    $_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];

}
?>
```